# How can I set fixed toolbar at the bottom of screen with DialogViewController in Monotouch?

Tags: xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I have DialogViewController I select some data from web service, and add root, and my root view height is always increase (like load more tweets) and I want to fix toolbar. However I didn't do it. when I add toolbar, it added end of root view, but I want that it should be fix on screen. Please help, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You should have the toolbar in your parent view controller. Look at the [UITabBarController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for an example.